# SQLite Bulk Import

Tags: sqlite, bulkinsert

I am sure there is no easy way to do this but I have ~400 excel files containing data.  Each excel file contains the same headers.  Is there an easy way of bulk inserting all 400 files at one time or in some form of batch process instead of doing in manually?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean with "manually"? is it manual by hand or a small application scanning and inserting one row at a time also classified as manual?

Comment: When I say manual I mean importing the whole excel file one by one using SQLite Maestro

Comment: I think Anna's solution (create a simple program) is the way to go, what programming language do you have in mind? I might be able to help a little there.

Comment: I am just going to create a simple C# win form app that uses GemBox to create giant data table and then save that data table to a local database.  I will take other ideas though.

Comment: you're on your way then! good luck mate :) just a tip though: I'd personally use simple insertion with parameterized SQLiteCommand, wrap it in transaction and commit it every 1000 rows or so (SQLite can't handle very large transaction very well with default settings from my experience).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your Excel files into a folder, then write a program to read their contents into a data table (either all at once or in batches) and then write the contents to DB using `SqlBulkCopy` class.

Comment: I think that is where I am headed.

Comment: save as csv files and import it.